# Pre-poulating UItableview with Core Data

Tags: xcode, sqlite, uitableview, core-data

Core Data is a new concept for me, though I am familar with SQLite. I am trying to find a tutorial about how to populate a table onload with data from core data. I am creating a database with hundreds of fields which will have detail views. I understand how to create this with `NSArray` but I am not sure as to which method to use for pre-loading my database into the UItableView. Should I preload it into coredata(which I read was possible) and then load it in? The UITableView is a static non-editable table. I want to include core data as it seems from my reading that it is taking over from SQL and is a more effective method to use. Below is a crude example of what I am trying to recreate.

[image: Im looking to recreate this]

I understand how to load arrays into the TableView with `NSArray arrayWithObjects` but this is not suitable for my purpose, nor is plist.

I did see an Apple Sourecode App called 'Recipe Book' that achieves what I am after but I was hoping there would be a source that could had broken down its creation or a similar tutorial.

So to clarify my question, I am looking as to the best method to pre-populate the UItableView from a database and if there are any handy tutorials about how to achieve this as the ones I have completed didn't provide what I was looking for.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at NSFetchedResults controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSFetchedResultController` is your friend.

I hope this [Apple sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html) will be a good starting point for you.
Also you can take a look to Ray Wanderlich [good example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller) of NSFetchedResultController